# Jinja2 sort dictionary based on last characters of key

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have the following yaml dictionary:

```
test:
  'xe-0/0/1':
      test: test
  'xe-0/0/2':
      test: test
  'xe-0/0/10':
      test: test
  'xe-0/0/3':
      test: test
```

I want to sort this for a loop based on the last number after the slash. Using the sort filter I get this

```
{{ test | sort }}

["xe-0/0/1", 
"xe-0/0/10", 
"xe-0/0/2", 
"xe-0/0/3"]
```

How can I get the sort right so 10 comes AFTER 3?